# What is this mod_security rule trying to prevent?

Tags: regex, mod-security

Today my IP was blocked by my server. I was told it was because of a mod_security rule that got triggered. I'm told that the regex that got triggered was

```
^((?:(?:POS|GE)T|OPTIONS|HEAD))
```

I don't know much about mod_security and was told

> If the regex
>   ^((?:(?:POS|GE)T|OPTIONS|HEAD)) is found
>   on any of the scripts on your account,
>   mod_security will trigger and block
>   access from that IP to the server.

**What exactly is this regular expression in mod_security looking to prevent?**

*I have run many of the files that I have uploaded to the server through this regex and didn't get any matches yet. I would like to know what this trying to accomplish so I can figure out, maybe, what caused the blocking and prevent it in the future.*

Comment: By the way, people who write regexes like `(?:POS|GE)T` instead of `^(POST|GET|OPTIONS|HEAD)` are being too clever at the expense of readability.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It refuses requests that are not using one of the accepted methods HEAD, GET, POST or OPTIONS. If you say, tried a WebDAV DELETE statement or something, it would then block that.